# How can I exit fullscreen mode and trigger my own function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

function openFullscreen() {
    if (class1[0].requestFullscreen) {
        class1[0].requestFullscreen();
      } 
    else if (class1[0].mozRequestFullScreen) {
        class1[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
      } 
    else if (class1[0].webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        class1[0].webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } 
    else if (class1[0].msRequestFullscreen) {
        class1[0].msRequestFullscreen();
      }
    }

function closeFullscreen() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } 
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } 
    else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } 
    else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
}

// Open fullscreen mode
class1[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    openFullscreen();
    class1[0].setAttribute("id", "whileFullscreen");
});

//"ESC" key closes fullscreen
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    if (x === 27) {
        class1[0].removeAttribute("id", "whileFullscreen");
    }
})
```

```css
/* ///// ///// */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* ///// ///// */

.class1 {
    border: 10px solid #00f;
    
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    
    background-color: #fff;
}

img {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    
    display: flex;
    
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

#whileFullscreen {
    display: flex;
    
    background-color: #000;
    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Key Event with Fullscreen Mode</title>
    <link href="css/KEFM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class1">
        <img src="" alt="Example Image"/>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script src="js/KEFM.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi,

I am creating a website for a photographer. From a "click" event I have the browser change to fullscreen mode whilst also triggering my own function to change various different css information. This works perfectly.

The problem is when I press the "esc" key to exit fullscreen mode I want it to also make changes to the css information. I have tried to achieve this with a "keydown" event listener also attached to the "esc" key.

The result is that the event won't trigger whilst in fullscreen mode so you have to press it again once fullscreen has been exited.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`onfullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onfullscreenchange) event for this.

First, lets bind to the event (you may want to do this for other browsers too):

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", closeFullscreen, false);
```

Note, the `onfullscreenchange` change event will fire on both open and close. So you'll also need to modify `closeFullscreen` to check if the event that is firing is to close the full screen mode. So inside the `closeFullscreen` function, wrap the code in:

```
if (!document.fullscreenElement){
    // Your current closeFullscreen code here
}
```

Then you can move the code for removing the ID into your `closeFullscreen` function too if you wish.

```
if (!document.fullscreenElement){
    class1[0].removeAttribute("id", "whileFullscreen");
    // Your current closeFullscreen code here
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you